# How do I find the values of arguments in an object?

Tags: java

I am creating a code that involves objects that have random arguments. Is there a way I can access the values of these arguments?

```
public class Bicycle{

  public Bicycle(int startCadence, int startSpeed, int startGear) {
      int gear = startGear;
      int cadence = startCadence;
      int speed = startSpeed;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Bicycle myBike = new Bicycle(30, 0, 8);
    int current_gear = myBike.gear; // accessing the value of gear
  }
}
```

Say I wanted to access the value of the current gear.. How would I go about doing that

Comment: Can you provide the code, or at least some of it?

Comment: public class Bicycle{

  public Bicycle(int startCadence, int startSpeed, int startGear) {
      int gear = startGear;
      int cadence = startCadence;
      int speed = startSpeed;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Bicycle myBike = new Bicycle(30, 0, 8);
    int current_gear = gear.myBike();
  }
}

Comment: Wait that didn't come out right

Comment: Well... I meant in the question but thanks.

Comment: There, that's better.

Comment: Ok i put it in the question

Comment: So, what are you asking: Accessing the parameters of the constructor INSIDE the class or OUTSIDE the class?

Comment: where do you want to access `current_gear`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
public class Bicycle{ 
    int gear;
    int cadence;
    int speed;
    public Bicycle(int startCadence, int startSpeed, int startGear) {
        gear = startGear; 
        cadence = startCadence; 
        speed = startSpeed; } 
    public static void main(String[] args){ 
        Bicycle myBike = new Bicycle(30, 0, 8); 
        int current_gear = myBike.gear; }
}
```

That way, you're making the `gear` variable a member variable. Then, whenever you need to access it use `myBike.gear`. Or, you could add a get method to your Bicycle class. Like this:

```
public int getGear(){
    return gear;
}
```

Comment: (1-) there is no reason for the static variables or method.

Comment: you don't need to make member variables `static`. They are being accessed using an object of class `Bicycle`.

Comment: Ok, Thank you for the help! Much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Bicycle{
  private int gear;

  public int getGear()
  {return this.gear;}

  public Bicycle(int startCadence, int startSpeed, int startGear) {
      this.gear = startGear;
      int cadence = startCadence;
      int speed = startSpeed;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args){
    Bicycle myBike = new Bicycle(30, 0, 8);
    int current_gear = gear.myBike();
    int theGearIWanted = myBike.getGear();
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you need the "this." before gear?